# Magento 2.2 credit card details hacked

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment

For a few days we have detected that in our Magento 2.2 the user is asked for their credit card details when it is something that was not done since the user is directly redirected to pay on the bank page.
Today a client told us that a charge had appeared on her card with which she bought on our casino page and we believe that the store has been hacked. Some help?

Comment: Hello, it seems strange, extensions do not store CC information... would you mind sharing your site URL and what payment gateway do you use for CC ?

Comment: We finally managed to find the problem. They were putting code in the footer of the page, it was eliminated and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Seem your site have some modules or included malware scripts that you don't know.
Try this tool in link https://github.com/gwillem/magento-malware-scanner may help